# Javascript strange behaviour in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript

I run [this code in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/obaveg/7/edit), And I get a console output as expected:

```
//matrix C before multiplySeq function call 
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
//matrix C after multiplySeq function call
[[6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6]]
```

However, when I run the same code Firefox and chrome, I get :

```
//matrix C before multiplySeq function call 
[[6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6]]
//matrix C after multiplySeq function call
[[6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6]]
```

I have no clue what's going on, can somebody point out what I might be missing here ?

PS: I get the desired output when I test in IE (wow, never thought I would ever say that)

Comment: clear your cache, I get the expected result.

Comment: not true.. i guess it is a caching issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [weird behaviour of javascript with arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766973/weird-behaviour-of-javascript-with-arrays)

Comment: Nope, don't think it's a caching issue. PS: I'm testing on FFv19.02 and chromev26.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have in Chrome and Firefox is that they don't build the display when you log, but when you browse the objects. That's why the first log display the final value.

You can get a more relevant result by cloning the value, for example

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(C2)));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/obaveg/10/edit)

Note that some versions of Chrome now issue a small **i** with a warning about this phenomenon.

Comment: Hmm interesting .. Could you point out to a link that elaborates more on this ? Thanks!

Comment: @potatoes I linked in comments to a previous answer. Apart the fact it's an often observed "known problem", I don't have any Google or Mozilla reference right now. You may use the solution I gave for simple objects (I also have a small lib working for large or cyclic objects).